# System requirements for Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

The system requirements for Ubuntu touch are not completely obvious to me.

> Ubuntu for Android drops in cleanly alongside the rest of Android, so
> it is easy to integrate into current production roadmaps. The hardware
> requirements are straightforward and, with a broad range of ARM and
> x86 hardware supported, it can realistically be added to phones
> already in development.
>
> Of course, your phone needs the docking capability and hardware
> support for HDMI and USB. But that’s standard for high-end models in
> the current generation of devices in development.

Well the "HDMI" requirement probably only applies if you want to use a monitor. I really want to install Ubuntu touch on my phone, is there a list of all supported hardware pieces available?

I am curious if it could work with http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_mini-3947.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this site https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Only The Sony Xperia S & T are currently, they are in Work In Progress although.

Forum devoted to Ubuntu Touch work in progress development

http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2068

Comment: Does this mean that ubuntu touch only works with those phones? I thought that the important thing is the hardware inside my phone. Like if the cpu / gpu in my phone already works in an already phone it should also work with my phone.

Comment: There is a forum that devotes its self to doing the conversion, so its a matter of someone with sufficient knowledge taking the time to do a port.